# Mailing Lists for Windows Live Mail contacts with multiple addresses

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-mail

I am using Windows Live Mail 2012. I have contacts with multiple Email addresses and want to build mailing lists using all addresses (not only the primary ones). I tried to build a category and edit it. No luck. I always end with a mailing list with just the primary addresses. Where is my mistake? Something I overlooked in the category editor? Another approach than categories?